# How to get the selected texts and display them?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is to grab the selected option from each of the selection boxes, click 'submit' and store them in the "stored" paragraph.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">
<button id="button" onclick="rolldices()">Roll dices</button>

<span id="dice1">0</span>
<span id="dice2">0</span>
<span id="dice3">0</span>
<span id="dice4">0</span>
<span id="dice5">0</span>
<span id="dice6">0</span>

<br><br><br><br>

<select id="select1">
<option>1
<option>2
<option>3
<option>4
<option>5
<option>6
</select>

<select id="select2">
<option>1
<option>2
<option>3
<option>4
<option>5
<option>6
</select>   

<select id="select3">
<option>1
<option>2
<option>3
<option>4
<option>5
<option>6
</select>

<select id="select4">
<option>1
<option>2
<option>3
<option>4
<option>5
<option>6
</select>   

<select id="select5">
<option>1
<option>2
<option>3
<option>4
<option>5
<option>6
</select>   

<select id="select6">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
</select>

<button id="submit" onclick="submit()">Submit your answer</button>  

<br><br>

<p id="correct">Correct numbers guessed: </p>
<p id="stored"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var numbers = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ];

var dices = [ 'dice1', 'dice2', 'dice3', 'dice4', 'dice5', 'dice6' ];

var select = [ 'select1', 'select2', 'select3', 'select4', 'select5', 'select6']

function rolldices() {

for (var diceindex=0; diceindex<dices.length; diceindex++) {

var dice_value = Math.floor((Math.random()*numbers.length));

document.getElementById("dice" + (diceindex + 1)).innerHTML=numbers[dice_value];

}

} // end of rolldices()
```

Here is my attempt at solving the problem:

```
function submit() {

for (var selectindex=0; selectindex<select.length; selectindex++) {

var e = document.getElementById("select" + (selectindex + 1));
var storedNumbers = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

document.getElementById("select" + (selectindex + 1)).text;
document.getElementById("stored").innerHTML=storedNumbers;
}





} // end of submit()
```

This works SORT OF, but only the last selectbox's text is being displayed in the "stored" paragraph.. What is wrong?

Comment: And the problem you're having with that is...? What's not happening that should be happening? What errors do you get? Have you debugged with the console?

Comment: @j08691 I'm not getting any errors, but the numbers stored are also not displaying in my paragraph. So I'm not sure what is the issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store every selected value and should display it. like

```
 var res = ""; //declare outside of function for store all value
 function submit() {
    //getting all select tags. 
    var allSelect = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var select=0; select < allSelect.length; select++) {
         var e = document.getElementById("select" + (select + 1));
         var storedNumbers = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
         res +=storedNumbers; //storing the selected values
    }
    document.getElementById("stored").innerHTML= res;
    res = "";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/suman_bogati/FdH5g/1/)

Comment: Your answer adds new stored numbers after each other tho if u click submit more than once.

Answer (score 0):

One immediate problem is that you are using select as an array and as a variable for counting  - change to

```
function submit() {

for (var i=0; i<select.length; i++) {

var e = document.getElementById("select" + (i + 1));
var storedNumbers = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

document.getElementById("select" + (i + 1)).text;
document.getElementById("stored").innerHTML=storedNumbers;
}
```

Comment: I changed it and now it semi works, but only the last selectbox's text is being displayed. Also added an edit to the last line in your answer which I forgot to add in mine, innerHTML= storedNumbers;

Comment: This is because storedNumbers may change as the loop progresses but the current value always overwrites the previous value so you are left with the last value

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't recommend attaching the handlers as HTML attributes. You should keep the logic and presentation separate. Also, instead of calling `getElementById` for each field (inefficient), I would just grab the select fields and filter them based on the ones you need. Here's how I would approach it:

```
var selectIds = ['select1', 'select2', 'select3', 'select4', 'select5', 'select6'];
var selectFields = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var stored = document.getElementById("stored");
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var values = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectFields.length; i++) {
        var select = selectFields[i];
        // One of our target fields
        if (selectIds.indexOf(select.getAttribute("id")) >= 0) {
            values += select.value;
        }
    }

    stored.innerHTML = values;
});
```

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SE8xM/).

Update:

An element needs to exist before you try to get a reference to it. One way to do this is to stick your script at the very bottom of your `body` tag.

For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // js here
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Is your script tag at the end of the document? Or are you selecting the elements after the `onload` event? If your answer to both is no then that's likely the problem.

Comment: It works in the fiddle but not in the browser.. Feels like there is a ) missing here: submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {?

Comment: I'm using an external file, but I solved the problem by going with another answer